# How to Display Real Time variables node.js with express

Tags: javascript, node.js

So , I have been try to display my variables "pares", "impares" ,"ninguno" in real time as the image below I used app.get and inside that a response.write to print de varibles, but the problem is if I want the varaibles to update, I need to reload the page everytime, is there anyway to print them in real time?,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBJ0S.png)

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var reload = require('reload');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);

var impares = 0;
var pares = 0;
var ninguno =0;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post('/arduino', function(request, response) {
    console.log("Arduino asking data");
    var stringInform = (Object.keys(request.body)).toString();
    var stringA = stringInform.split("|");
    var dato1= parseInt(stringA[0],10);
    var dato2 = parseInt(stringA[1],10);
    response.send('Hello Arduino'); 
    Parimpar(dato1,dato2);
    response.end();
    console.log(dato1);
    console.log(dato2);
    console.log(ninguno);
});

 app.get('/arduino', function(request, response) {
    response.write('PARES:'+ pares + ' '+ 'IMPARES:' + impares + ' ' + 'NINGUNO:'+ ninguno);
    response.end();   
});


app.listen(8080);

function Parimpar(c,i)
{
    if (c%2 == 0  && i%2 == 0)
    {
        pares = pares +1;
    //  return pares;
    }
    else if (c%2 != 0 && i%2 != 0)
    {
        impares = impares + 1;
        //return impares;
    }
    else
    {
        ninguno = ninguno +1 ;
        //return ninguno;
    }



}
```

Comment: Use [Session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use Web-sockets To Emit Events When The Values Are Updated . The Easier Way Is to Setup A socket.io webserver and emit values to all the connected values.
Check Out https://socket.io/

Comment: Hello, can you please give me an example on how to do it. or implement it to my code, I am new to node.js